# write cell value based on an array of row numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the word "nice" that I want to write into a column. Normally I would get the range `targetColumn.getRange(2, 7, sheetLR-1)` and then just `.setValue('nice')` to write it into the desired rows of that column.

But I want to write the word only into specific rows of that column/range. I have an Array in which the indexes of the rows are stored, like [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 14]. How can I write "nice" into the rows of the column by using the array that holds my row indexes?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm an absolute beginner and I am completely failing at this. I think there is no way to do this. If I had to guess I would say maybe use the array with the indexes to loop through the rows/range and set the value "nice" per loop cycle? Even if that would be the way, I'm far able from realizing it :(

Comment: Good idea. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the rows in an array. Use array. indexOf().

```
If(array.indexOf(current row)>-1){
//do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: that is not the right direction. I already have an array with the indexes of the rows. based on that I want to fill the cells with a value/word "nice".

Or maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This function writes the word 'nice' into the specified rows

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 14]; // which rows to write in
  var column = 1;                  // target: column A
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  for (var i in array) {
    var target_row = array[i];     // gets the values from array
    sheet.getRange(target_row,column).setValue("nice"); 
  }
}
```